# calculadora javascript, resultado NaN

Tags: javascript-objeto, calculo

*Cuando escribo así los comandos result.value = **NaN**, aquí uso las propiedades fuera de la función.*

```
var num1=document.getElementById('sum1');
var num2=document.getElementById('sum2');
var result=document.getElementById('outCalc');
var a=parseFloat(num1.value)
var b=parseFloat(num2.value)
function sumarN(){
    result.value=a+b;
}
```

*Pero cuando los arreglo así se corrige:*

```
var num1=document.getElementById('sum1');
var num2=document.getElementById('sum2');
var result=document.getElementById('outCalc');
function sumarN(){
    result.value=parseFloat(num1.value)+parseFloat(num2.value);
}
```

**Alguien me explique el PORQUE, puesto que si uso la propiedad VALUE dentro de la función, sí corre mi código correctamente.**

Comment: En la primera, `result` es una variable local de la función; deja de existir al salir. En la segunda, `result` es una variable global; existe desde antes que llames a la función (y después, obvio).

Comment: num1.value y num2.value, en la primera opción se está ejecutando cusndo se crea la pantalla. El usuario todavía no cargó el valor y, por lo tanto, a y b van a estar vacíos. la suma da NaN. En la segunda opción recién estas leyendo el valor cuando vas a hscer la suma y ahora (seguramente) hayas cargado un valor. Si agregas un console log de la variable a y b, te vas a dar cuenta lo que digo.

Comment: sí, tienes razón Franco, gracias. No se porqué no me di cuenta...

Answer (score 0):

En el **parseFloat** va **parseInt**

```
let num1 = document.getElementById('sum1');
let num2 = document.getElementById('sum2');
let result = null;
const sumarN = ()=>{
    result=parseInt(num1.value)+parseInt(num2.value);
    return result;
}

console.log(sumarN())
```

Y te recomiendo usar **let** para hacer tus variables por que el **var** es una variable global que se puede usar desde dentro de otros bloques de codigo y en cambio el **let** NO por que solo se puede usar en su respectivo codigo y el **const** es una variable en la que no puedes cambiar su valor.

**Explicacion:**

El **parseInt** sirve para parsear **Strings** a **Numbers** aunque el **parseFloat** se usa para aceptar una cadena y convertirla en un número de punto flotante, te felicito por eso. Y cuando creas una función debes de llamarla con el nombre que le distes o si no, no dara resultado tu función